# DBus Secret Service prompting

Tags: gnome, dbus, gnome-keyring-daemon

Hi I'm attempting to utilize the [Secret Service](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/latest/) to access secrets in Gnome Keyring.

Everything works ok if the collection I'm trying to access is already unlocked. The problem I'm running into is when the collection/secrets are locked and it needs to prompt for the user to input their password to unlock it.

According to the docs

> Operations that require a prompt to complete will return a prompt object. The client application must then call the Prompt() method of the prompt object to display the prompt. Client applications can use the window-id argument to display the prompt attached to their application window.

The [Prompt() method](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/latest/re05.html#org.freedesktop.Secret.Prompt.Prompt) is supposed to exist within org.freedesktop.Secret.Prompt per the docs.

I'm using D-Feet to try to find that, but nothing matching that name shows up in either the Session or System bus.

[image]

[image]

Any idea if this has moved? Or if I should be doing something else to display the prompt?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get given the prompt object by some other operation? I'm assuming that if you do an operation that requires the user to login then it return the prompt D-Bus object for you to use. Is that not what's happening?

Comment: Right, org.freedesktop.Secret.Service has a function "Unlock" that returns an ObjectPath for the prompt. Which I believe I'm supposed to provide to the Prompt method in org.freedesktop.Secret.Prompt though I could be entirely wrong there...
I'm using C# so the function I'm calling looks like Task<(ObjectPath[] unlocked, ObjectPath prompt)> UnlockAsync(ObjectPath[] Objects);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test I've done was using the create a new collection functionality as I found this the method that was easy to do that issued a prompt.

There are two object paths returned from `CreateCollection`

> collection
>
> ```
> The new collection object, or '/' if prompting is necessary.
> ```
>
> prompt
>
> ```
> A prompt object if prompting is necessary, or '/' if no prompt was needed.
> ```

I then used the prompt object to call the `Prompt` method with a random window ID. I waited for the prompt `Completed` signal before continuing.

A screenshot of the prompt:

[image: Prompt from secrets]

From the comments I can see you are using C#, unfortunately I don't know that so I have done my tests in Python. I'm hoping there is enough similarity to help move you forward.

```py
from pydbus import SessionBus
from gi.repository import GLib

properties = {"org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection.Label": GLib.Variant.new_string("MyCollection")}

ses_bus = SessionBus()
service_name = 'org.freedesktop.secrets'
secret_service = ses_bus.get(service_name, '/org/freedesktop/secrets')

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()


def _received_pw(dismissed, object_path):
    print("dismissed?", dismissed, object_path)
    mainloop.quit()


def show_prompt(prompt_id):
    prompt = ses_bus.get(service_name, prompt_id)
    prompt.onCompleted = _received_pw
    prompt.Prompt("random_id_for_window")
    mainloop.run()
    print('Prompt closed')


def add_my_collection():
    result = secret_service.CreateCollection(properties, "")
    print("result from CreateCollection", result)
    if result[1] != '/':
        show_prompt(result[1])


def remove_my_collection():
    for test_collect in secret_service.Collections:
        if "MyCollection" in test_collect:
            this_collection = ses_bus.get(service_name, test_collect)
            result = this_collection.Delete()
            if result != '/':
                show_prompt(result)


def main():
    add_my_collection()
    remove_my_collection()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which gave the output:

```
result from CreateCollection ('/', '/org/freedesktop/secrets/prompt/p1')
dismissed? False /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/MyCollection
Prompt closed
```

I've been using `busctl` to monitor what has been created. For example:

```
$ busctl --user tree org.freedesktop.secrets 
└─/org
  ├─/org/freedesktop
  │ ├─/org/freedesktop/portal
  │ │ └─/org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
  │ └─/org/freedesktop/secrets
  │   ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/collection
  │   │ ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/MyCollection
  │   │ ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
  │   │ │ ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1
  │   │ └─/org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/session
  │   ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/prompt
  │   │ ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/prompt/p1
  │   │ └─/org/freedesktop/secrets/prompt/u2
  │   └─/org/freedesktop/secrets/session
  │     ├─/org/freedesktop/secrets/session/s1
  └─/org/gnome
    └─/org/gnome/keyring
      └─/org/gnome/keyring/daemon
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me to the right answer, had to do a little extra with the library I'm using in C# to get the Prompt interface generated but everything worked after that!
For anyone in the future using Tmds.Dbus for this - https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus/issues/175